# Style the nth letter in a span using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, styling, pseudo-class

I have:

```
<span id="string">12h12m12s</span>
```

and I'm looking to make the `h`, `m` and `s` smaller than the rest of the text. I've heard of the `nth-letter` pseudo element in css, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```css
#string:nth-letter(3),
#string:nth-letter(6),
#string:nth-letter(9) {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

I know I could use javascript to parse the string and replace the letter with surrounding `span` tags and style the tags. However, the string is updated every second and it seems parsing that often would be ressource intensive.

Comment: Because such a thing does not exist. You've probably read it from a blog suggesting its implementation - see http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/ and scroll down to "::nth-letter() / ::last-letter() / ::nth-last-letter()" - and yes, you can easily achieve this with JS.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, I had a feeling... Could you suggest another way of doing this (in js I assume) that would be efficient enough to be run every second?

Comment: Maybe something like this http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx

Comment: I've used JavaScript to create a clock which uses span elements to contain the hours, minutes, seconds. If you give each of these span elements a unique id attribute, you can simply use JavaScript to target and update the content of just that element. Performance is excellent, and you can use CSS to style each component differently.

Comment: @Arkanon, that was my backup plan -- sounds like its my _only_ option. I'll give that a go, thanks.

Comment: +1 @Arkanon That's a good solution. Don't forget to cache the DOM element references for even better performance. `=]` The issue arrives when you're using something like Moment.js running on an `setInterval`, editing its source is no easy feat.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, I'm not familiar with caching DOM elements, mind sharing a link?

Comment: What I meant is e.g. before the loop: `var seconds = document.getElementById('seconds');` then use `seconds` instead of `document.getElementById('seconds')` inside the loop. Here's a more detailed article: http://www.phpied.com/dom-access-optimization/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, oh, right. I thought there was some fancy way of caching things in javascript. Thanks

Comment: V8 has a lot of hidden witchery that compiles your JS and optimizes "hot" functions as well as de-optimizing, but yeah, to us mere coders, JS just has objects which we can store references to. (in this case, DOM element interface objects).

Comment: BTW you didn't specify whether you're using a library to generate that time or if it is your own function, either way if you supply the code in the question or a fiddle I'll provide a more on-topic answer. `:P`

Comment: I just noticed there is i think only two calls to the jQuery function on this entire post :-) (I love jQuery, just thought that was interesting).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Performance-wise, I'd recommend a `span` hell.

```
<span id="string"><span id="h">12</span><span class="h">h</span><span id="m">12</span><span class="m">m</span><span id="s">12</span><span class="s">s</span></span>
```

One span for each `h`, `m` and `s` letters so you can style them properly (can apply either the same or different styling for each).

And another span for each number so you can cache the references. In sum, here's a JS for a very simplistic local-time clock:

```
//cache number container element references
var h = document.getElementById('h'),
    m = document.getElementById('m'),
    s = document.getElementById('s'),
    //IE feature detection
    textProp = h.textContent !== undefined ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

function tick() {
    var date = new Date(),
        hours = date.getHours(),
        mins = date.getMinutes(),
        secs = date.getSeconds();
    h[textProp] = hours < 10 ? '0'+hours : hours;
    m[textProp] = mins < 10 ? '0'+mins : mins;
    s[textProp] = secs < 10 ? '0'+secs : secs;
}
tick();
setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rsfax/2/)

This illustrates the basic idea of cached selectors. By not re-creating the elements, you also have a good performance boost.

Though, once a second isn't very heavy work for something so simple (unless you have hundreds of clocks in your page).

Comment: That was the most entertaining intro to an answer

Answer (score 3):

This might be a long winded way of doing this using javascript and jQuery, but here's a possible solution.

Separate the `h`,`m` & `s` from the original string.

```
string = $('#string').text();

hD = string.substr(0,2)
h = "<span>"+string.substr(2,1)+"</span>";
mD = string.substr(3,2)
m = "<span>"+string.substr(5,1)+"</span>";
sD = string.substr(6,2)
s = "<span>"+string.substr(8,1)+"</span>";

finalString = hD + h + mD + m + sD + s;

$('#string').html(finalString);
```

Then you can style the spans within `#string` with CSS.

```
#string{font-size:1.2em}
#string > span{font-size:0.8em}
```

Here is a [demo fiddle showing the above](http://jsfiddle.net/sLgZE/).

Answer (score 3):

This only throws the letters in spans and gives them all the same class. Maybe worth an honorable mention lol :-)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsGQ9/11/)

JavaScript:

```
var str = document.getElementById('string'),
    chars = str.innerHTML.split('');

for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (chars[i].match(/[hms]/)) {
        chars[i] = "<span class='smaller'>" + chars[i] + "</span>";
    }
}
str.innerHTML = chars.join('');
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <span id="string">12h12m12s</span>        
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.smaller {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can delete the whole for loop, and replace the final line with:

Comment: str.innerHTML=str.innerHTML.replace(/([hms])/gi,'<span>$1</span>');

Comment: The css then becomes: *#string span{font-size:10px}

Comment: If you want to style them individually, use for each, this css: *#string span:nth-of-type(n){...css...}, where n is the ordinal number of the span, and ...css... is whatever css you want for each

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution with CSS and wrapping each character with a span-tag:

```
#text span:nth-child(2) {
  color: #ff00ff;
}

#text span:nth-child(5) {
  color: #00ffff;
}

#text {
  font-size: 20px;
}

<span id="text"><span>H</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span>o</span></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f8vffLj0/