# Different colors for alternate letters in a word

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

I want to give green (or any other) color for alternate letters in a word.

How can I do this using CSS?
**Jquery also fine for me**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does your HTML look like? You need to add some tags around the letters you want to have a different color.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994270/style-the-nth-letter-in-a-span-using-css

Comment: I edited the title to read 'alternate letters'... it's clear that that's what he meant

Comment: I'd recommend using http://letteringjs.com/ & nth-letter(), otherwise you'll go mad.

Comment: Thanks everybody for answering me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use jQuery, you could use this code snippet:

```js
$( "span" ).each(function( index ) {
  var originalText = $( this ).text();
  var newText = "";
  for( var i = 0; i < originalText.length; i++)
  {
      if (i % 2 === 0)
        newText += "<span>" + originalText.charAt(i) + "</span>";  
      else
        newText += originalText.charAt(i);
  }
  $( this ).html(newText);
});
```

It replaces the wanted characters with a span inside the original span, and you can then style that span.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m6RTW/

Comment: y did u give `if (i % 3 === 0)` 3 instead of 2 ?? any way thanks @Metoule

Comment: Ooops for some reason I saw 3.. I've edited my answer to use 2 instead.

Answer (score 7):

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/JeyJD/)**

HTML

```
<div class="try">
<span>G</span>
<span>d</span>
<span>d`s </span>

<span>O</span>
<span>w</span>
<span>n </span>

<span>C</span>
<span>o</span>
<span>u</span>
<span>n</span>
<span>t</span>
<span>r</span>
<span>y</span>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.try span:nth-of-type(even){
    color:green;
}
.try span:nth-of-type(odd){
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the letters inside a `<span>` and style them.

```
<p style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:34px;">
G<span style="color:green">o</span>d'<span style="color:green">s</span>
o<span style="color:green">w</span>n c<span style="color:green">o</span>u<span style="color:green">n</span>t<span style="color:green">r</span>y
</p>
```

[jsFiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/x3QVY/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply `CSS` to text which is not more than 10 letters then u can break it in span and apply class to it.

```
<span class="green">H</span>
<span>E</span>
<span class="green">L</span>
<span>L</span>
<span class="green">O</span>

.green
{
    color:green;
}
```

Comment: You can still use the same technique but it will be too tedious job.

Answer (score 0):

Put chosen letters inside span tag and add styles.

css:

```
.green {
    color: green;  
}
```

html:

```
<p>G<span class="green">o</span>d'<span class="green">s</span> o<span class="green">w</span>n co<span class="green">u</span>n<span class="green">t</span>r<span class="green">y</span></p>
```

Or add even/odd class (cross browser solution):

```
<div class="colors">
    <span class="odd">a</span>
    <span class="even">b</span>
    <span class="odd">c</span>
    <span class="even">d</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.colors .odd {
    color: red;
}
.colors .even {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS can only be applied to whole elements. So you need to divide your text into elements. You can do this by hand, or javascript, or HTML generation.

To keep the HTML short, you could do this: (see http://jsfiddle.net/9TY4J/)

```
<SPAN class="fancyColors"><B>G</B>o<B>d</B> .... </SPAN>
```

And write a CSS:

```
.fancyColors
{
    color:red;
}
.fancyColors B
{
    color:green;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```