# how to change middle letter size in a word using html

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement like, I want display one letter in a bigger size Ex: focus. in this I want to display 'O' in bigger size. I tried with font tag and it is not working. Please suggest a solution in HTML.

If I use p tag with style attribute, word is breaking.

Comment: Can you add a span inside of your text? And to you mean one letter in particulary, or given by index?

Comment: Try <p style="display:inline">text</p>

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate question, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994270/style-the-nth-letter-in-a-span-using-css

Comment: @EmreAcar Why abuse `<p>` when there is `<span>`?!

Comment: yes... span tag works... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>F<span style='font-size:1.5em;'>o</span>cus</div>
```

Comment: <span style='font-size:12px;'>F</span><span style='font-size:35px;'>o</span><span style='font-size:12px;'>cus</span>

Comment: The above tag works... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try ..

```
f<strong>o</strong>cus
```

or

```
f<span class="big">o</span>cus
```

in css

```
.big{font-size:32px}
```