# Is there a way in CSS to capitalize specific letters of text?

Tags: css, css-selectors

For a given text node on a page...

```
abcdefghijklmnop
```

You can capitalize all letters with this:

```
selector {
    text-transform : uppercase;
}


/* Output: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP */
```

You can capitalize just the first letter with this:

```
selector {
    display : block;
}

selector:first-letter {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

/* Output: Abcdefgijklmnop */
```

Is there any way to capitalize specific letters in the string besides the first letter? Example:

```
/* Pseudo code */
selector:nth-character(odd) {
    text-transform : uppercase;
}

/* Output: aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoP */
```

Comment: A simple google would answer this for you, and the answer is no. You need Javascript.

Comment: I think you need this: http://letteringjs.com/ Not possible with pure CSS.

Comment: Agree with the other comments, I'm afraid this is not possible with CSS alone as it cannot select text nodes. The only way this could be done with CSS is by changing the HTML and surrounding the letters in elements.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Thank you for telling me that Google exists.  Of course, when I Google this question in there, this very SO page the most relevant result I get. :)

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994270/style-the-nth-letter-in-a-span-using-css

Comment: I just spent half an hour searching the web, determined to prove everyone wrong, thinking 'it MUST be possible with CSS only...' but alas I have failed. If the individual letter you want to replace is in it's own `<span>` or something it's easy to do with just CSS (a SO search brings up loads of examples of how to do it), but looking at a string of letters in the same class and replacing one of them based on logic/what you tell it? Definitely a Javascript thang I'm afraid. Dammit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ***not*** possible currently with **pure CSS**. But you can use the [**letteringjs.com**](http://letteringjs.com/) plugin to implement it. You can read the [**Lettering.js Docs**](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".custom-caps").lettering();
});
```

```css
.custom-caps > span:nth-child(even) {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/master/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
<div class="custom-caps">abcdefghijklmnop</div>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="custom-caps">abcdefghijklmnop</div>
```

**Rendered HTML:**

```
<div class="custom-caps">
  <span class="char1">a</span>
  <span class="char2">b</span>
  <span class="char3">c</span>
  <span class="char4">d</span>
  <span class="char5">e</span>
  <span class="char6">f</span>
  <span class="char7">g</span>
  <span class="char8">h</span>
  <span class="char9">i</span>
  <span class="char10">j</span>
  <span class="char11">k</span>
  <span class="char12">l</span>
  <span class="char13">m</span>
  <span class="char14">n</span>
  <span class="char15">o</span>
  <span class="char16">p</span>
</div>
```