# how to make an uppercase title <h1> to sentence case "Like this example" using css

Tags: html, css

As per the title, i am trying to change my  from this "EXAMPLE TITLE" to this "ExaMple title".

Please note that i am using two uppercase characters in the same sentence.
If that is not possible then can you recommend a css that would make it sentence case like this "Example title"

EDIT:I already have some suggested duplication of my post, but i am looking for a different thing. I have to use the  tag for SEO purposes which forces the character to become uppercase so i need to have a lowercase css for a few of the characters not the whole sentence

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make the first character uppercase in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577364/make-the-first-character-uppercase-in-css) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994270/style-the-nth-letter-in-a-span-using-css

Comment: Thanks that is different though. I have to use the <h1> tag for SEO purposes which forces the character to become uppercase so i need to have a lowercase css for a few of the characters not the whole sentence

Comment: There is NO CSS method to do this. You will either need alternative HTML or Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao Angelo, I can’t help you with your first case *“ExaMple title”* but I’m pretty sure you can get *“Example title”* with the following code:

HTML:

```
<h1>EXAMPLE TITLE</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 { text-transform: lowercase; }
h1:first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

EDIT: You wrote that H1 tag forces your text to uppercase, this is not a standard behavior of that tag, this means that you have already a CSS rule like this:

```
h1 { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Can’t you remove that line from your current CSS?

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? I think that I am in topic and really trying to help.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, maybe missing this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8pabsvj/) :) But i rather guess that someone wanted to discourage you from answering what he thought was a bad question, until the question was improved by the OP. Don't take it personally.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

HTML :

```
<h1>ExaMple title</h1>
```

CSS :

```
h1 {font-variant-caps: unicase;}
```

This will result as the HTML input.

> ExaMple title

I prefer this way usually when attach unique key such as token ID which have upper & lower case in mix order